# SSL configuration for shiny server open source

Tags: r, shiny, https, web-config, shiny-server

I have a virtual server from our university for deploying my shiny apps. Before SSL certificate was installed on my server, I was running shiny apps on port 3838 correctly. Recently, I decided to use the HTTPS protocol for my server. I set port 443 using the ssl.cofig file and the default port in httpd config file is port 80. The shiny server settings port is also 3838. When I use the HTTPS address like https://ier1.tums.ac.ir:3838 in the browser, I can't see Shiny apps both in our university network and also from out of university where I see error 502. When I am on the university network shiny apps load just on http protocol. Apache loads correctly on HTTPS both in university and out-of-university networks. The Settings files ([ssl](https://github.com/mehdihadi/shiny-config/blob/main/ssl.conf), [shiny.server](https://github.com/mehdihadi/shiny-config/blob/main/shiny-server.conf) and [httpd](https://github.com/mehdihadi/shiny-config/blob/main/httpd.conf)) are on my GitHub addresses. Please let me know your recommendation. I tried many methods but none of them worked. Thanks

Comment: After several trials and error efforts I find the solution. The following code resolved the problem: setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1

Answer (score 0):

After several trials and error efforts I find the solution. The following code resolved the problem:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```